# Speed Up Access to Fractal-Like Array

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to speed up the following function in c++:

```
void num_to_xy(int num, int *x, int *y):
    *x = (cl & 0x03) | ((cl & 0x10) >> 2) | ((cl & 0x40) >> 3) | ((cl & 0x100) >> 4) | ((cl & 0x400) >> 5) | ((cl & 0x1000) >> 6) | ((cl & 0x4000) >> 7);
    *y = ((cl & 0x0c) >> 2) | ((cl & 0x20) >> 3) | ((cl & 0x80) >> 4) | ((cl & 0x0200) >> 5) | ((cl & 0x0800) >> 6) | ((cl & 0x2000) >> 7) | ((cl & 0x8000) >> 8);
```

which basically converts `num` to an x,y coordinate.  This is equivalent to getting the x,y position of `num` in the following array

$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
0 &1 &4 &5 &16 &17 &20 &21 &...\\
2 &3 &6 &7 &18 &19 &22 &23 &...\\
8 &9 &12 &13 &24 &25 &28 &29 &...\\
10 &11 &14 &15 &26 &27 &30 &31 &...\\
32 &33 &36 &37 &48 &49 &52 &53 &...\\
34 &35 &38 &39 &50 &51 &54 &55 &...\\
40 &41 &44 &45 &56 &57 &60 &61 &...\\
42 &43 &46 &47 &58 &59 &62 &63 &...\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &
\end{array} \right|$

The array above follows a pattern where for all $k,n$, all numbers between $k4^n$ and $(k+1)4^n-1$ form a perfect square.

Can the code above be sped up without generating a ginormous list and storing all the values?  Or is there a completely different, faster method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the fastest approach with modern CPUs is

```
i = num & 255
j = num >> 8
*x = x1[i] + x2[j]
*y = y1[i] + y2[j]
```

That is 4 arithmetic ops plus 4 loads